# PHP Not Showing Errors on Fresh Install of Apache/PHP on Ubuntu Server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2, configuration

I just tried a simple hello world with a semi colon missing, and I'm getting a blank page.

Any ideas why PHP refuses to show errors?

A script without errors works perfectly.

Also, I remember reading somewhere that there's an example config file that Apache or PHP come with that needs to be renamed to remove the  .sample or something like that.

Since I'm not much of a server admin, I'd much rather go with whatever sample Apache/PHP has provided. Where can I find this sample configuration? Perhaps it'll fix this (and other problems yet to appear).

PHP script I'm testing with (missing semicolon)

```
<?php
    echo "Hello"
    echo "sup";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display_errors = On` in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.

Comment: I tried this and it's still not displaying errors

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: I had not, but I just restarted apache and tried it again. Still no errors :(

Comment: Is there something I need to configure in my vhost file?

Comment: Odd, I can't seem to turn "off" error outputting now and I'm sure I crossed the same bridge as you a couple of weeks ago with Ubuntu 10.04.2LTS/PHP and found `display_errors`.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder what's wrong

Comment: Ok, brain fart.  Just did an install of PHP5 and apache2 on another Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS virtual machine, changed `display_errors` to `On`, created foo.php with `<?php thisshouldthrowanerror ?>` and sure enough, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE".

Comment: Hmm, so it's working for you on a fresh install. I wonder what I did to mess it up. I've changed nothing but the vhost settings.

Comment: OK, It works if i place use the ini_set method in my PHP file. But how come the php.ini directive isn't working? Is there any place I could place the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, you need both

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

and maybe even

```
display_startup_errors = On
```

E_STRICT is not strictly necessary, but I think it's best practice to report those too.

However, you should **only do this on a development server**. Displaying errors can lead to security problems such as leaked passwords. You may want to be setting these values in your web app's configuration section - based on whether the web server is a development or production server.

```
  if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'my.production.url') {
    ini_set('display_errors', false);
  }
  else {
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
  }
```

Note that $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] may not be reliable if virtual hosting is configured such that you can also load the website via an IP address. In this case, substitute an alternative test that works in your environment (eg getting the server's hostname, or testing to see if the REMOTE_ADDR is localhost).

Comment: Hey dimmer, I tried all 3 directives you've listed above, and errors still will not display. I've updated my post to show the PHP script I'm testing with.

Comment: Update provided on gravyface's answer

Comment: Are you testing via the web server or command line?

Comment: I'm testing via web server

Comment: If you haven't already try restarting via `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` - sometimes `apache2ctl` doesn't get the job done.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to help either. Maybe I messed something up along the way and if nothing can be found, then I'll just rebuild it from a fresh install